# Shell scripting: Contact list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have no idea how can I do this. I need to make an menu option where you can search a contact by his nick, and then modify his data.
For example:

> Name - Nick - Phone - Mail
>
> John - Johnny - 123456789 - john@test.lan

What I have till now it is:

```
 add(){
    read -e -p "Name: " name
    read -e -p "Nick: " nick
    read -e -p "Phone: " phone
    read -e -p "Email: " mail
    echo $name "-" $nick "-" $phone "-" $mail >> list
    }

 mod(){
    read nick
    grep $nick list
    #Don't know how to continue this... :-/
    }
```

This function can be also used for search user info. So I think that I can pass the result to a temp, change there and after that to pass the info to the original file... but not sure if this will be the best option and if I know how to do this.

Also I need to do some more options: delete contact, add contact and a function that should look if there are blank lines (remove them), contacts that have only the NICK (remove and save a reg).

Comment: Using dash as separator isn't robust, people have hyphens in names, phone numbers, and email addresses. I would suggest either tab-delimited or CSV (with all its idiotic conventions, it's reasonably standard and well-supported by tools).

Comment: To read lines from a piped file, `echo $* |while read l; do ...; done`; alternatively there are a whole sleuth of Unix commands for just this purpose (created in the early days - one of the reasons Unix was popular was people liked its text processing abilities): `cut`, `ex`, `fmt`, `fold`, `join`, `awk`, `paste`, `sed`, `sort`, `tr`, `uniq`, `vi`, `xargs`.  Are fixed column widths not the native approach to a record CRUD problem rather than CSV?  Is there any particular reason you need to use a shell script, a perl module would sort this out in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Don't know how to continue this... :-/

here is an idea:

```
read nick
record2modify=$(grep $nick list)

name=$(echo ${record2modify}| awk -F "-" '{print $1}')
nick=$(echo ${record2modify}| awk -F "-" '{print $2}'); orignick=${nick}
phone=$(echo ${record2modify}| awk -F "-" '{print $3}')
mail=$(echo ${record2modify}| awk -F "-" '{print $4}')

selection="Z"
while [ ${selection} != "D" ]
do

clear
echo " "
echo " "
echo "What will you modify ?"
echo " "
echo "[N]ame"
echo "Nic[k]"
echo "[P]hone"
echo "[M]ail"
echo " "
echo "[D]one (upper case D only)"

read -e -p "Please make your choice" selection

case ${selection} in 
  N | n) read -e -p "New Name" name;;
  K | k) read -e -p "New Nick" nick;;
  P | p) read -e -p "New Phone" phone;;
  M | m) read -e -p "New Mail" mail;;
  
  D) echo "Finished modifying...";;
  *) clear; echo "Make a valid selection"; sleep 3;;
esac

done


sed -e "/${orignick}/d" list > list.tmp

echo ${name} "-" ${nick} "-" ${phone} "-" ${mail} >> list.tmp
mv list.tmp list
```